# Adding Windows 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit DC to Windows 2008 Standard 32 bit Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

All of our domain controllers (2) are Windows 2008 Standard 32 bit.
We are trying to add a Standard 2008 R2 64 bit domain controller to the forest but for some reason during DCPROMO, we receive the following error:

> "to install a domain controller into this active directory forest,you
>   must first prepare the forest using "adprep/forestprep" etc

We went ahead an ran adprep /forestprep on our established domain controller and allowed time to replicate.  When attempting to execute dcpromo again, we receive the same error.  What gives?

Comment: You need to run the adprep from the **R2** disc on the 2008 domain controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run adprep /forestprep **ON** the existing DC holding the Schema Operations Master role. You need to run adprep/domainprep /gpprep **ON** the existing DC holding the Infrastructure Master Operations Master role. You run adprep **FROM** the W2K8R2 installation DVD. If you're running it on a 32 bit DC then you'll need to run the 32bit version of adprep (adprep32.exe). Adprep can be run from the \sources\adprep folder on the W2K8R2 installation DVD.

Comment: +1. This is more complete than my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the adprep and forestprep commands **from the 2008 R2 DVD** *on the DC that currently holds the Schema Master role as a member of the Domain Admins group*

Comment: If you don't know where that is run  "netdom query fsmo" from a commandline and that will give you all the FSMO role holders.